# How to show all match value from a list using excel formula

Tags: excel-formula

I have a list of project that include Project id, start, end date, and staff

I would like to try to show the Project id if I input the new project with start, end, staff overlap with the existing project:
[image]

I am trying to list out the Project id using INDEX and MATCH, but it only gives the 1 result, is there any way to list the remaining matched result? (the correct result is 1, 3)
thanks.

Comment: what version do you have?

Comment: If you do not have TEXTJOIN() it will require the use of a helper column or vba.

Comment: Hi @ScottCraner, yes I have TEXTJOIN() version :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Screenshots/[here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j98kHZcXeI_laW5xoU?e=COA705) refer:

**Version 1**

*Pre-requisite*: Office 365 compatible version of Excel.

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",0,FILTER(A2:A4,--(B2:B4<=H2)*(C2:C4>=G2)*(D2:D4=I2)))
```

[image: Version 1- Office 365]

**Version 2**

One method, for Excel versions that are not part of the Office 365 package, as follows:

*Interim calc:*

```
=IF(--(G2<=C2:C4)*(C2:C4>=B2)*(D2:D4=I2)*(D2:D4=I2),A2:A4,"")
```

*Return concatenated soln (copy down adjacent to column M values per interim calc above):*

```
=IF(N1="result",M2,IF(M2="",N1,N1&", "&M2))
```

[image: Version 2- interim calc]

[image: Version 2 - copy down to concatenate desired result]